# In Julia, how do I repeat a character n times creating a string like in Python?

Tags: python, julia

In Python it is easy to create a string of `n` characters:

```
>>> '=' * 40
'========================================'
```

However, in Julia the above does not work.  What is the Julia equivalent to the Python code above?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Julia you can replicate a single character into a string of `n` characters, or replicate a single-character string into a string of `n` characters using the `^` operator.  Thus, either a single-quoted character, `'='`, or a double-quoted single character, `"="`, string will work.

```
julia> '='^40  # Note the single-quoted character '='
"========================================"
julia> "="^40  # Note the double-quoted string "="
"========================================"
```

Another way to do do the same thing is:

```
julia> repeat('=', 40)
"========================================"

julia> repeat("=", 40)
"========================================"
```

Comment: And [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Concatenation-1)'s an explanation of why Julia chooses `*` and `^` instead of `+` and `*` for string concatenation: because the latter symbols are usually used for commutative operations, which concatenation isn't.